# Was the pre-special relativity discussion a hot topic in the late nineteenth and early twentieth century?

Tags: physics, relativity-theory, electromagnetism, einstein

We know that low-dimensional materials and topological materials are some of the current hot topics in Physics.

Did this happen with the pre-special relativity discussions in the late nineteenth and early twentieth century, too?

I couldn’t get a conclusion reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_special_relativity

Comment: There were no electronic communications or social networks back then, so it is unclear what you mean by "hot topic". The negative outcome of Michelson-Morley experiments was discussed by top physicists in the field (Hertz, Fitzgerald, Lorentz, Larmor, Poincare) and various clever explanations suggested, but that much is clear from Wikipedia. As Kelvin's and Michelson's remarks suggest, there was also an excited anticipation of a "grand unification" of physics based on ether, see [Kragh's book](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s6683.html).

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for your attention. I think this can be an answer! Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what "pre-special relativity" means?

Answer (score -1):

Once electromagnetism produced a lot of awards in that time and it were researched by top physics, I think not exactly special relativity but Electromagnetism were a hot topic. Thanks @Conifold.